# Getting assertion failed error in gtk.

Tags: c, gtk, signals, gtk3

I'm new to using GTK. Here is a small section of my code. The aim is to copy the entire current line. The contents are stored in "line". "start" and "end" are textiter at start and end of line.

```
gtk_text_iter_set_line_offset (start, 0); 
gtk_text_iter_forward_to_line_end (end);  
line = gtk_text_iter_get_text (start, end);

gtk_clipboard_set_text (clipboard, line, -1);
```

And upon execution, Im getting the following error messages.

```
Gtk[27786]: CRITICAL: gtk_text_iter_set_line_offset: assertion 'iter != NULL' failed
Gtk[27786]: CRITICAL: gtk_text_iter_forward_to_line_end: assertion 'iter != NULL' failed
Gtk[27786]: CRITICAL: gtk_text_iter_get_text: assertion 'start != NULL' failed
Gtk[27786]: CRITICAL: gtk_clipboard_set_text: assertion 'text != NULL' failed
```

What is wrong with the code block? How can i resolve it?
Thanks all :)

Comment: You give to those functions NULL pointers instead of C strings. Please give more code to understand where is the error.

Comment: Consider adding how `start` and `end`  are defined here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably got your iterators declared like `GtkTextIter *start`. Instead, according to the [text widget conceptual overview](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/TextWidget.html) in GTK's documentation, "`GtkTextIter` is a struct designed to be allocated on the stack; it's guaranteed to be copiable by value and never contain any heap-allocated data." This means you should not declare them as pointers:

```
GtkTextIter start, end;
// ...
gtk_text_iter_set_line_offset (&start, 0); 
gtk_text_iter_forward_to_line_end (&end);  
line = gtk_text_iter_get_text (&start, &end);
```